# Honeypot hidden field in webform template "webform--contact.html.twig"

Tags: webforms

Honeypot is active on my site (Drupal 9) for all forms. When I created the template file for the contact form "webform--contact.html.twig", I can't get the honeypot default hidden field "url".

I tried :

- {{ content.url }}
- {{ element.elements.url }}
  ...

How can I get the honeypot hidden field "url" in my contact twig file?

```
/* templates/webform/webform--contact.html.twig */

  <form{{ attributes }}>
        {{ title_prefix }}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.elements.email }}
            //  Honeypot hidden field "url" ? 
                ...
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.elements.message }}
            {{ element.form_build_id }}
            {{ element.form_token }}
            {{ element.form_id }}
            {{ element.elements.actions }}
          </div>
        </div>
        {{ title_suffix }}
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me `{{ element.url }}` works. It seems to me that Honepot does not add the field to the elements subarray. And be sure not to be logged in with a role that has the permission to bypass honeypot protection.

Tip: with Devel module and Xdebug installed you can set a breakpoint in your twig file with `{{ devel_breakpoint() }}` which allows you to stop your script at this point and check which variables can be used in your twig file.

Comment: Thank you @Tobias for this response.